# ef core return just the included entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

in ef core I have a contract entity which has a paymentRequirement entity. I want to bring back just the payment requirement entity given the contract's id.

```
public async Task<PaymentRequirement> GetPaymentRequirementByContractAsync(long Id) =>
            await context.Contracts.Include(p => p.PaymentRequirement).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == Id)?.PaymentRequirement
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'Task' does not contain a definition for
>   'PaymentRequirement' and no accessible extension method
>   'PaymentRequirement' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly
>   reference?)   Minerals    C:\Users\c-bdelling\source\repos\Minerals\Minerals\Repositories\PaymentRequirementRepository.cs 15  Active

here is the contract

```
 public class Contract : AuditedEntity
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }       
        public long? PaymentRequirementId { get; set; }
        public PaymentRequirement PaymentRequirement { get; set; }

    }
```

here is paymentrequirment

```
 public class PaymentRequirement
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public decimal? FloorPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: why are you using `?`  ?

Comment: in case contract does not exist like the id was 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the entire expression is being awaited, and `PaymentRequirement` is not awaitable:

```
context.Contracts
    .Include(p => p.PaymentRequirement)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == Id)?
    .PaymentRequirement
```

You really need to be awaiting the result of `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, and you can do this by introducing parenthesis:

```
(await context.Contracts
    .Include(p => p.PaymentRequirement)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == Id))?
    .PaymentRequirement
```

Having said this, there should be a cleaner way of doing this, assuming `PaymentRequirements` is a `DbSet` on your context:

```
await context.PaymentRequirements
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => context.Contracts
        .Any(c => c.Id == Id && c.PaymentRequirement == p));
```

That way, only the `PaymentRequirement` and not the `Contract` will be returned from the database.